# WD My Cloud very slow

Tags: hard-drive, home-networking, cloud-storage

I just bought a WD My Cloud 3 TB, connected it to my modem and connected 6 devices to it.
Currently I am getting very slow response times, 0.5 - 3 seconds while browsing the files. (and it is empty) 
My file writing speed seems to be 15 MB/s max.

Is this normal or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Sounds like the router/modem/gateway its connected to has USB 2.0 ports instead of USB 3.0 ports.

Comment: Router is connected with an ethernet cable to my WD Cloud, my pc is connected to my router with an ethernet cable also.
I am transferring files from another HDD which probably uses USB 2.0.
Still I think this file transfer speed is very low and it doesn't explain the response time at all.

Comment: My dropbox currently has more storage in it and has a much faster response time, while browsing.

Comment: Your transfer speeds cannot be helped because your plugging in a USB 3.0 device into a USB 2.0 port.  RJ-45 is 10/100/1000 which means the only reason it would be slow would be if the modem only has a 10/100 port.

Comment: It is Airties RT-212 wireless modem. My ports on my pc are USB 3.0, but the device might be USB 2.0.
Still I thought USB 2.0 should reach 30 MB/s not 10

Comment: 30 MB/sec would be the theoretical limits.  Everything has to be perfect to reach those limits.  The datasheet didn't indicate what speed the RJ-45 port was.  If you provide that I will provide a full answer, explaining your poor data transfer rates.

Comment: Don't have a clear answer but it is leaning towards 100mbps

Comment: You have your answer then.  Your network connection is only 100 mbps instead of 1000 mbps.  Its 10 time slower.

Comment: Disable DLNA in the settings. I was having the same problem (5-10 sec browsing times) and disabling DLNA instantly fixed it. See https://wdc.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/11383/~/performance-on-a-wd-my-cloud-or-wd-my-cloud-ex4-degrades-and-becomes

Comment: @Esqarrouth What is the max transfer rate you get from the Drive? I only manage maximum of 17mbps - Do you get more than this? I have 1GB LAN But this drive is just slow as hell

Answer (score 4):

WD My Cloud is a piece of shi.... slow and unreliable + they want you to use their app which is basically a WD skinned finder. I'm very very disappointed. my speed limit with the disk is 10-15mb/sec over wifi while it is the speed I have while downloading from the internet through wifi on my mac book pro... the disk is slower than internet...

**ANSWER WHY IT IS SLOW**

WD My Cloud is slow **because** it is connected on a **100** mbps LAN network which means the max transfer speed is 100/8 -> **12.5** MO/sec you can know if your WD My Cloud is on a 100 Mbits or a 1 Gbits network by looking at the led next to the RJ45 plug. If it's orange, it's 100 Mbits that you have. if it's green it's 1Gbits. What you want is a 1Gbits LAN network -> get a better router...

Comment: If you're transferring data over wifi; keep in mind wifi N tends to max out around 50-150mbps (lower than its rating, but in the real world this is typical), with G tending to 25-50 and AC in the 200-250 range. For devices over wifi, a 100 vs 1000 connection on the WD only really makes a difference if you have multiple devices communicating with it at once. What I do (I have a Seagate Central) is I don't even use the switch built-in to my ISP's crappy wifi router; I just bought a cheap gigabit switch, hooked everything including the wifi router into that, and all is smooth.

Comment: (And I have my laptop connected via a wired connection when I'm at my desk, and my desktop is always wired - that's where the speed to the Seagate Central is gained.) Also the read/write performance of your local hard drive can easily be a bottleneck, especially for lower RPM and/or old drives.

Comment: I have 1GB Lan, doesn't go faster than 18mbps, averages around 15mbps Up and 17mbps down. I wish I spent a little more and bought something like Synology NAS or something else.

Answer (score 1):

Good day everyone:-)
I too have been experiencing very slow response times while browsing files on my 4TB Cloud. I am running a Docsis 3.0 modem with 1000kbps USB although it is not connected trough USB but rather though TCPI. My OS is win 7 64 bit.

Contacted WD and was given this page to run a scan on my 4tb my-cloud to diagnose issues that might be the cause of this problem.
http://support.wd.com/product/download.asp?groupid=904&lang=en
Have this ready before calling WD as to speed up the process. For WIN 7 64 bit in the box on the right where it says Knowledge Base Enter keyword, phrase, answer ID, or PID? Enter 940. If you have a different model and or OS ask WD Tech and they will give you the correct code to enter. I will post results after test is complete. Hope this helps you.
God Bless

Comment: is the test complete?

Answer (score 1):

The issue of slowness has MORE to do with the constant and poor coding used for rescanning/indexing of files by Western Digital. The default setting for rescanning/indexing is -1 which basically means re-index after ANY change. The process can take many hours.

I followed this page and corrected the issue. https://seo-michael.co.uk/improving-the-performance-of-wd-mycloud/

The essential change I made to improve performance is here: 

1- through your browser, go to twonky (http://wdmycloud.local:9000/) 

2- go to advanced 

3- go to rescan intervals 

4 – change it to 0 (or a larger value in minutes. 1440 is every 24 hours) 

5- save (at bottom) this stops it scanning itself completely every time a file moves. 

6- go and rescan your database

If the value is set to 0, then if you make changes to your file structure go back to advanced and select rescan.

By following the above steps your NAS will work better.

Comment: What is your maximum transfer rate you get from the drive? I only manage 17mbps on 1Gbps LAN.

Comment: I get about 11MBs to my 2tb mycloud and 120MBs to my 4tb mycloud device. The 2tb drive us older.

Comment: Do you have the WD Discovery app installed? How do you get 120mbps? Do you have the `MyCloud Home` ? How do you transfer your files to it?

Comment: Hi Pierre,   my 4tb drive that supports about 120MBs is a 1-bay personal cloud storage(gen2). The firmware version is 2.31.195. My 2tb drive only states the firmware is 4.5.0.  I'm simply using a unc path to copy to folders from the same laptop to compare transfer rates.  The rescan setting is set to 0 on both.

Comment: Pierre, both devices have green lights on the ethernet ports, but I'll try swapping cords and ports to see if the speeds change. It does feel like the older 2tb drive is limited to 100mbs, not 1gbs.

Comment: I contacted WD (3 week process) - They came back with "In the end, this device is not designed for super fast transfer speeds, I do apologize for this, but the My Cloud Home is the simplest device we offer, for ease of access, not performance." - So the "MyCloud Home" is SH17...

Comment: I just swapped out the ethernet cables and the speeds DID swap. The 2tb drive transferred at 10pMBps and the 4tb drive dropped to 11MBps. So I believe the combination of lowering the rescan interval AND ensuring the other equipment supports 1Gbps will improve the transfer rate. It sounds like your equipment is set to 100Mbps as stated by other posters.

Comment: Typo 10pMBps should be 100MBps. Sorry.